# Can anyone help identify this rose?

Tags: identification, roses

I love the look and scent of this rose in my garden, which was here when I moved in. Can anyone please help me to identify it?

It is about 6-7ft at its tallest point, and the stems seem fairly long rather than bushy. I don't think it has been pruned particularly.

Thank you very much in advance.

[image: flower]
[image: part of bush]
[image: part of bush]
[image: part of bush]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *Rosa* 'Handel'. Take a look [here](https://www.britishroses.co.uk/acatalog/Handel.html).